# Example of output_signature , output_types & output_shapes for complex object called by tf.data.Dataset.from_generator

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I've a generator function that yields the following tuple: `yield (transformed_input_array, set_y)`

*transformed_input_array* is a list of ndarrays with the following shape: *(1024, 104), (1024, 142), (1024, 1), (1024, 1), (1024, 1), (1024, 1), (1024, 140)*  and the following types: *tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.int8, tf.int16, tf.int8, tf.int8, tf.float64*
*set_y* is a ndarray of shape *1024* and type of *int64*

I've wrapped my generator with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator function, here is the code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator,
    # output_signature=(
    #     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=(tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.int8, tf.int16, tf.int8, tf.int8, tf.float64)),
    #     tf.TensorSpec(shape=1024, dtype=tf.int64))
    output_types=(tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.int8, tf.int16, tf.int8, tf.int8, tf.float64, tf.int64),
    output_shapes=((1024, 104), (1024, 142), (1024, 1), (1024, 1), (1024, 1), (1024, 1), (1024, 140), 1024)
)
```

But when I run the training, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Data is expected to be in format `x`, `(x,)`, `(x, y)`,
> or `(x, y, sample_weight)`, found: (<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0'
> shape=(1024, 104) dtype=float64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1'
> shape=(1024, 142) dtype=float64>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2'
> shape=(1024, 1) dtype=int8>, <tf.Tensor 'It eratorGetNext:3'
> shape=(1024, 1) dtype=int16>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4'
> shape=(1024, 1) dtype=int8>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5'
> shape=(1024, 1) dtype=int8>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:6'
> shape=(1024, 140) dtype=float64>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0'
> shape=(1024, 1) dtype=int64>)

If I try to run with output_signature param (commented out code), I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert value (tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.int8,
> tf.int16, tf.int8, tf.int8, tf.float64) to a TensorFlow DType.

**Can someone provide an example, of how I should treat complex type (list of ndarrays)?** Couldn't find any example in TF documentation..

Comment: This function may help [tf.type_spec_from_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/type_spec_from_value) returns a `tf.TypeSpec` that represents the given value.

Comment: Any answer to this?